# Encrypt Array Give Arbitrary Trash Randomly

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption

So, I have a project where I have to input a string from cin into an odd array and then, starting at the center, "spin out" clockwise and print the encrypted message.

For the most part, I have it working just fine. However, it prints arbitrary trash for some inputs and I cannot figure out why. Most of the "problematic" inputs seem to have * and spaces, but even some simpler ones give me problems.

Some of the "bad examples" are:

```
"* * ** * * ** * ** ***  ** ** **"
"**************************************************************************************"
"**********    "
"hello world how are you doing?"
```

(`""` left out when attempting to run them, I just put he there so you can see the beginning and end of each test)

Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    int direction=0; //right = 0, down = 1, left = 2, up = 3
    int n, size, i = 0;
    char data[33][33];
    int x, y;
    int stepCount=1, numStep =0;


    getline(cin, message);
    n = message.size();

    size = sqrt(n);

    x = y = size/2 + 0.5;

    if(size*size < n){
        size++;
    }
    if(size%2 == 0){
        size++;
    }

    for(int r=0; r < size; r++){
        for(int c=0; c < size; c++){
            data[r][c] = message[i];
            if(!message[i]){
                data[r][c] = '*';
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(int a=0; a<size*size; a++){
        cout << data[x][y];



       switch(direction){
            case 0: y += 1;
                    break;
            case 1: x+= 1;
                    break;
            case 2: y -= 1;
                    break;
            case 3: x -= 1;
                    break;
       }


       numStep++;
       if(numStep == stepCount){
        direction = (direction+1)%4;
        numStep = 0;
       }
       if(x == y){
        stepCount++;
       }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by: *So, I have a project where I have to input a string from cin into an odd array and then, starting at the center, "spin out" clockwise and print the encrypted message.*  I do not understand.

Comment: You have `char data[33][33];`. Are you sure that `size` will never, ever be 33 or more?

Comment: @MFisherKDX - Basically, the user inputs a message of choice. My code is supposed to put that message into an odd array(to create a perfect 'center' value). Then, starting at this center value, I have to 'spin out' and print the encrypted message.  Without being able to draw it for you, it's hard to explain. But, imagine a table with x rows and y columns. The string is input across row one, then across row two, and so on until the string ends. Then, excess space is filled with * until the array is filled. Starting @ the center square, I "spiral out"(1 right, 1 down, 2 left, 2 up, etc.) the msg

Comment: @BoPersson my professor told us that the string would be a maximum of 1000 characters. So, a 33 x 33 array should hold all 1000 characters and is the first 'odd' array to do so.

Comment: If it's printing random trash, it probably means you're accessing uninitialized array elements.

Comment: @Barmar but how if the original array is restricted to 33 x 33 and none of the test cases have a size larger than that? Also, any unfilled space of the array is filled with "*". I just don't understand what would cause me to overflow into those uninitialized elements.

Comment: `message[i]` can access outside the size of `message`, because when you do `size++` it can make `size*size >= n`. That causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar my `if(!message[i])` statement doesn't protect that by filling in those spaces with "*"?

Comment: No, @Barmar is right.  `i` goes from 0 to size*size-1.  The message is slightly shorter.

Comment: Also `if(x == y){ stepCount++; }` is only valid on the diagonal.  Which is not what you want.

Comment: also, make sure to test with the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".  This is `n=26` characters.  Your `size = sqrt(n)` makes `size 5` so you could still be accessing uninitialized values in your array.

Comment: @MFisherKDX thank you! I was able to figure it out :) Using Barmar's suggestion and I also had to add one to size if `sqrt(n)/size != 1` because of the issue you pointed out. That fixed all of the problems I was having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop that fills in `data[r][c]` can access nonexistent elements of `message`, because `size*size` will be larger than `message.size()` if either of the conditions that increments `size` is true. You need to check if `i` is outside the message.

`if (!message[i])` is not the correct way to check this; when `i > message.size()`, the result of `message[i]` is undefined, not `false`.

```
for(int r=0; r < size; r++){
    for(int c=0; c < size; c++){
        data[r][c] = i < n ? message[i] : '*';
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped me and I was finally able to figure it out :)